# error in updating mysql with $.post using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i wanna have like for my blog posts, it should work like this: user will click on something and it increase that number by +1 and store it in data base, i have a column named post_like in my db. but after increase 0 to 1 (when i try to increase from 1 to 2 or more) i get error.
jquery:

```
 $("#insert_like").click(function(e){
        alert('s')
        var like = $("#insert_like").val();
        like += 1;
        var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
        $.post("./inc/like.php", {
            like: like,
            post_id: post_id
        }, function(data, status){
            $("#insert_like").text(data);
            like = 0;
        });
    });
```

php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['like'])) {
    require_once 'db.inc.php';
    $like = $_POST['like'];
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];




    $q = "UPDATE posts set post_like = ? WHERE post_id=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $like, $post_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
        echo "$like";
    } else {
        echo "error: $stmt->error";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
} else {
    header('Location: ../home.php');
}
```

html:

```
<p>Post like: <span id="insert_like" style="cursor: pointer"><?php echo $post_like ?></span> </p>
```

Comment: And what is the error? And btw if I modify `#insert_like` html contents to some greater number you will update data too? So instead of 10 likes there will be 2500.

Comment: idk it just says error, this "error" comes from php else code.(`else {echo "error: $stmt->error";}`. and how exactly you want to change  `#insert_like` html? i mean it's not an **input**!

Comment: By using developers console and editing html.

Comment: @Technotures `#insert_like` can still be modified and it plays a crucial role in your database interaction, so that's most likely a security concern

Comment: OK any advice or tip or article about this situation (security concern)? i get it it's a security concern, but where error comes from?

Comment: You can just pass the post id and run the sql query in the backend to update the likes. See answer below.

Comment: You still have to find error text. What shows in case of error? Just `error: ` string?

Comment: yes just that `error: ` string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the Post Id from javascript and update the likes in the backend. Consider below example:

```
$("#insert_like").click(function(e){
    $.post("./inc/like.php", {
        post_id: $("#post_id").val()
    }, function(data, status){
        $("#insert_like").text(data);
        like = 0;
    });
});
```

and in the backend

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['like'])) {
        require_once 'db.inc.php';
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

        $q = "UPDATE posts SET post_like = (post_like + 1) WHERE post_id = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $post_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
           // get the updated likes and return as response.
        } else {
           echo "error: $stmt->error";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    } else {
        header('Location: ../home.php');
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @u_mulder this works but i think with this code user cannot modify html am i right? cause it increases like by 1 every time